# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException

Tags: java, android, sqlite, exception

I don't use sql lite in my application but it's trowing this error. Any ideas on why that is?

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: error code 10: disk I/O error 
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:61)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1809)
at android.webkit.WebViewDatabase.flushCacheStat(WebViewDatabase.java:769)
at android.webkit.CacheManager.trimCacheIfNeeded(CacheManager.java:558)
at android.webkit.WebViewWorker.handleMessage(WebViewWorker.java:190)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what code to post here. I have no idea what's causing the error?

Comment: Yahor10 - This isn't my device it just shows up in the error logs inside the google play portal

Comment: Dave did you resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

This error is probably caused by some ad view.
Advertising SDKs like AdMob are usually based on Webviews, sometimes causing errors like this one.

Do you use an ad SDK ?

Comment: That's probably it, I'm using admob sdk. Is there a way to prevent this somehow?

Comment: From my experience with several ad SDKs, there will always be some (rare) crashes on some devices. You can still contact AdMob support for help, but I don't think they will be able to fix it or help you find a workaround. This exception is most likely caused by a problem on the device (faulty or full internal memory, buggy custom ROM etc...)